# Hover not working

Tags: css, html5, reactjs

Estoy intentando hacer una cinta animada pero he tenido suerte haciéndola.

Cuando uso el cursor sobre la identificación izquierda, funciona, pero cuando trato de usar RibbonContainer o la identificación derecha, no funciona.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi CSS

```
#RibbonText {
  background: #5bdfb8;
  color: #009;
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: width .5s, padding-right .5s, visibility .5s;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  line-height: 30px;
}

#RibbonContainer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 10px;
  left: -6px;
  transition: width 2s, box-shadow 2s;

  #left {
    height: 33px;
  }
}

#RibbonContainer:hover + #RibbonText {
  width: 100%;
  visibility: visible;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Este es mi HTML

```
<div className="RibbonContainer">
      <img id="left" className="RibbonImage" alt="ribbon-shwadow" src={ribbonShadow} />
      <span id="RibbonText" className="ribbon">
        {ribbonText}
      </span>
      <img id="right" className="RibbonImage" alt="ribbon-end" src={ribbonEnd} />
</div>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a S.O. Español, traduce tu pregunta al Español, ,  [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: gracias por el comentario

Comment: Está claro que no funcionará sobre el contenedor, el hover lo estás declarando solo en la identificación izquierda cuando dices `#left:hover`. Usa `.RibbonContainer:hover > #left{}` y debe solucionarse el problema.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta, funciono @JaimeMenéndez